# Line in kickstart config is not running?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, kickstart

I use kickstart to automate the installation of custom centos 7. And everything is fine until this line in the kickstart config inside the `%post` section.

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /script.sh
echo "bash /tmp/dcos/dcos_install.sh slave" >> /script.sh
chmod 755 /script.sh
chmod 755 /tmp/dcos/dcos_install.sh
/script.sh
```

I'm not sure whether it's permission problem or the kickstart totally skip executing these lines. Is there a way to run command as root in kickstart?

Comment: Why do you do this indirection? If you mean to run `/tmp/dcos/dcos_install.sh slave` then you could just run it directly.

Comment: I did run it directly at first and it doesn't work so I change to the above code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the script you're trying to run, then.

Comment: I can run it manually .

Comment: What does the log say? it can be found in: /tmp/install.log. also, is it possible that the dcos_install.sh file has been edited in Windows?

Comment: Hi, Itai Ganot. I changed the ways to run this script. Instead of running it while ks installation. I append the script into rc.local and its run on the first boot of centos instead and the script removed from rc.local after the first run. Cheers !